# Button setting up a pictore inside one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I know that code:

```
$('#leftDev').css("background-image", "url(img/1.png) ");
```

will make a whole background of my leftDiv filled with "1.png", but I need to set it as a regular picture, in certain position (not in entire div as a background). How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#leftDev').append('<img src="img/1.png" alt="" />');
```

or perhaps

```
$('#leftDev').html('<img src="img/1.png" alt="" />');
```

It's hard to know without some context.

http://api.jquery.com/prepend

http://api.jquery.com/append

http://api.jquery.com/html